# Slack - behind a “firewall“

Tags: websocket, intranet, slack-api, slack

I've try to create a slackbot. Works fine, but my problems are calls from slack to my rest api. My app is an internal service, so it's not available from the internet. I have seen that outgoing webhooks is possible to set, but I have to forward the request back to the internal service which I don't like very much. As far as I know slack is based on websockets, so is it possible to write a bot which run behind my “firewall“ and  get it's commands via websocket?

Greetings
Tonka

Answer (score 3):

You can use services like [Localtunnel](https://localtunnel.github.io/www/) for receiving webhooks behind a firewall.

We use it with a [docker container](https://hub.docker.com/r/kaixhin/localtunnel/) to develop our slack bot in local env.

Answer (score 1):

Webhooks, slash commands, interactive messages, events etc. are based on HTTP. 
Only [bots](https://api.slack.com/bot-users) use websockets.

But even this bot websocket session still needs to be initiated with an HTTP call.

Not entirely sure how your firewall is set up, but you may want to make your endpoint public to make things easier.